# Runing time of Recursive Algorithm as recurrence

Tags: algorithm, recursion, runtime, recurrence

I  came across a question asking what the running time of the following recursive algorithm is.

```
  int F(int A[ ],int N) {

    if(N==1)

    return 1 ;
    return F(A,N-1)+1
}
```

The answer is O(N), but I just don't know how to justify it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to count the number of recursive calls this function is making, and the number of operations done under each recursive call.

So each time the function is called, there is 1 if call, and 1 return call.

The recursive call is of the form `F(A,N-1)` so N is getting decremented by 1 in every call, and your base case is N=1 i.e. there will be no more recursive calls when reaches 1.

So intuitively it is obvious that there are N recursive calls, and since each call is doing operations in constant time (hence is negligible), the overall running time is O(N)

I hope that explains.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the running time by the recursive time equation:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1
```

And then expand the recursion:

```
T(n) = (T(n-2) + 1) + 1 = T(n-2) + 2 = (T(n-3) + 1) + 2 = T(n-3) + 3 =
... = T(1) + n - 1 = n = \Theta(n) = O(n)
```